# Split data to multiple person with the reference data set

Tags: r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

i need to split data into multiple persons with the reference data set

Data 1

```
Numbers
680
183
856
661
916
240
68
390
393
722
241
627
77
439
162
943
185
931
117
```

Data 2

```
Team
A
B
C
D
```

Output

```
Numbers Team
680 A
183 A
856 A
661 A
916 A
240 B
68  B
390 B
393 B
722 B
241 C
627 C
77  C
439 C
162 C
943 D
185 D
931 D
117 D
```

Comment: Not enough information... Not clear

Comment: What is your allocation rule for making teams? Also, please post your reproducible code for the inputs and show what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate or related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318333/680068

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660903

Answer (score 0):

Use `rep()` in combination with the `each`- and `length-out`-arguments

In this example I used `data.table`.

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("Numbers
680
183
856
661
916
240
68
390
393
722
241
627
77
439
162
943
185
931
117")

team <- fread("Team
A
B
C
D")[[1]]
```

**code**

```
dt[, Team := rep( team, 
                  each = ceiling( nrow(dt)/length(team) ), 
                  length.out = nrow(dt) )]
```

**output**

```
#     Numbers Team
#  1:     680    A
#  2:     183    A
#  3:     856    A
#  4:     661    A
#  5:     916    A
#  6:     240    B
#  7:      68    B
#  8:     390    B
#  9:     393    B
# 10:     722    B
# 11:     241    C
# 12:     627    C
# 13:      77    C
# 14:     439    C
# 15:     162    C
# 16:     943    D
# 17:     185    D
# 18:     931    D
# 19:     117    D
```